# Pass by refrence instead of by value OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am not very experinced when it comes to working with C++ and I was given some code from [Andrey Smorodov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542806/andrey-smorodov) when I use the method it is not manipulating the image. I believe it is being passed by value and once the method is done running the variables are gone. Can someone please tell me if passing by references vs value is what is wrong? When I comment out the method it does not change the result image.

Method:

```
void CalcBlockMeanVariance(cv::Mat Img,cv::Mat Res,float blockSide=21) // blockSide - the parameter (set greater for larger font on image)
{
    cv::Mat I;
    Img.convertTo(I,CV_32FC1);
    Res=cv::Mat::zeros(Img.rows/blockSide,Img.cols/blockSide,CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat inpaintmask;
    cv::Mat patch;
    cv::Mat smallImg;
    cv::Scalar m,s;

    for(int i = 0;i < Img.rows-blockSide;i+=blockSide)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<Img.cols-blockSide;j+=blockSide)
        {
            patch=I(cv::Rect(j,i,blockSide,blockSide));
            cv::meanStdDev(patch,m,s);
            if(s[0]>0.01) // Thresholding parameter (set smaller for lower contrast image)
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=m[0];
            }else
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=0;
            }
        }
    }

    cv::resize(I,smallImg,Res.size());

    cv::threshold(Res,inpaintmask,0.02,1.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    cv::Mat inpainted;
    smallImg.convertTo(smallImg,CV_8UC1,255);

    inpaintmask.convertTo(inpaintmask,CV_8UC1);
    inpaint(smallImg, inpaintmask, inpainted, 5, cv::INPAINT_TELEA);

    cv::resize(inpainted,Res,Img.size());
    Res.convertTo(Res,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);


}
```

Calling the method:

```
  cv::Mat cvImage = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];
    cv::Mat res;
    cv::cvtColor(cvImage, cvImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cvImage.convertTo(cvImage,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    //CalcBlockMeanVariance(cvImage,res);
    res=1.0-res;
    res=cvImage+res;
    cv::threshold(res,res, 0.85, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::resize(res, res, cv::Size(res.cols/2,res.rows/2));
    cvImage.convertTo(cvImage,CV_8UC3,255.0);
    _endImage = [self UIImageFromCVMat:cvImage];
```

Could I be losing any data when converting back to a `UIImage`?

Here is my resulting image:

[image]

The result Andrey got using this method:

[image]

Could anyone explain why I might be getting such a different result compared to Andrey?
Thanks

Comment: Btw, remember to do the preprocessing before you call this function and the postprocessing after getting back the result as described in Andrey's code in your previous post. Otherwise you wouldn't get his result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function definition to the following:

```
void CalcBlockMeanVariance(const cv::Mat &Img, cv::Mat &Res, float blockSide=21)
```